# How to enable entering username in Zorin OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, active-directory, zorin

I have joined my zorin os (v8) to a domain.  But I can not find how to enable entering usernames on the logon screen.  How do you enable this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Zorin OS 8 to test but to do this in version 9 do the following:

Open Terminal and type the following:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-zorin-greeter.conf
```

Then add in at the bottom line:

```
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

Save and reboot, you will now have a login option which will ask for username and password.